# Laptop cannot detect Kindle Fire HD 8.9 in Device Manager

Tags: adb, amazon-kindle-fire

I have an old 8.9" Kindle Fire HD (model 3HT7G) and it is stuck in a recovery boot loop. I have found a way to get it out of this loop, but I need to use my laptop. The problem is, when I plug in my device, it does not appear in Device Manager and there is no indication that the device has been detected by the computer. The only thing that happens is that the Kindle starts to boot up (as standard for when you plug it in). Is there any way I can fix it? Maybe drivers are the issue, but I installed the USB drivers and adb drivers and I have tried all the methods I have found online...

Comment: @RahulParashar I have installed the Google USB driver and the ADB drivers from the Android SDK Manager. I have also installed the Kindle Fire USB driver

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the adb drivers from this [link](https://adb.clockworkmod.com/), then reboot your pc.

> > Next installing the USB drivers for the Kindle from Amazon.

(Windows user) Uninstall the existing USB driver

If you are a Windows user who previously connected a Fire tablet without first enabling ADB, you will need to remove the existing USB device driver and force re-installation of the driver.

1. Connect your Fire tablet to the USB port on your development computer.
2. On the development computer, from the Start menu, right-click Computer, and then click Control Panel.
3. On the control panel page, then click Device Manager.
4. In the Device Manager window, expand Portable Devices.
5. Right-click the Fire device and then click Properties.
6. In the Properties window, on the Driver tab, click Uninstall, and then Confirm.
7. Unplug your Fire tablet from your computer.

---

Install the USB driver for Windows.

Perform the following steps if your development computer runs Windows.

1. You can directly download the USB driver from the following URL:

   https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-sdk-manager/redist/kindle_fire_usb_driver.zip
2. Extract the zip folder into a new folder.
3. Open the new folder and run the executable file, which installs the driver.

---

Source:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/ft-set-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing.html#windows-user-uninstall-the-existing-usb-driver

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/ft-set-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing.html#windows-user-install-the-usb-driver-for-windows

Comment: I have already installed all of those drivers and still my kindle fire isn't being detected in device manager.

Comment: https://adb.clockworkmod.com/  use this..?

Comment: Yes I did use that